# I tried using htacess for seo friendly rewrite.it successfully redirected but href on the redirected page also had the redirected url

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

This is my rewrite url. www.xxx.com/deal/f should be redirected to www.xxx.com/deal.php?shopid=1.

```
RewriteRule ^deal/f$ deal.php?shopid=1 [NC,L]
```

Even though it successfully redirected the other normal url on that page such as www.xxx.com/contact.php is being shown as www.xxx.com/deal/contact.php and all links are dead because of this.
Kindly help me in this
My htaccess code for additional information:

```
# Use PHP5.4 as default

AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .php

RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ index.php?username=$1

<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
  # Compress HTML, CSS, JavaScript, Text, XML and fonts
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/vnd.ms-fontobject
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-opentype
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-otf
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-truetype
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-ttf
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/opentype
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/otf
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/ttf
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/svg+xml
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/x-icon
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/javascript
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml

  # Remove browser bugs (only needed for really old browsers)
  BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html
  BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip
  BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html
  Header append Vary User-Agent
</IfModule>
```

Comment: You have shown us something wrong. Your rewrite rule can't recirect to `/deal/contact.php`.

Comment: No...i meant the links on the page deal.php?shopid=1 are coming as www.xxx.com/deal/sdhksdkh.php instead of www.xxx.com/sdhksdkh.php

Comment: pls find the probelm here:http://rewardsinn.com/deal/sd    .Kindly help me in this

Comment: Remove all the code from your .htacces, except for `RewriteEngine On RewriteRule ^deal/f$ deal.php?shopid=1 [NC,L]` Does it still redirect incorrectly?

Comment: I tried doing what you said...it didn't work....same problem as before http://rewardsinn.com/deal/f getting extra /deal on every link on that page,,,,pls help me in this

Comment: Your RewriteRule looks correct. I think, something else is causing trouble.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please add 301 or 302 redirection code to redirect for incoming URL request.

```
RewriteRule ^deal/f$ deal.php?shopid=1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: kindly help me in this